# htaccess turn on php flags if certain IP address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I need to turn on the following:

```
php_flag display_errors On
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
```

However I only want to do this if my IP is visiting the site.

Any ideas?

Something like...

```
if (ip == "x.x.x.x") {
  php_flag display_errors On
  php_value error_reporting 2147483647
}
```

Need to do this in .htaccess NOT in the PHP thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this in the httpd configuration. Consider using a script in [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this in Apache 2.4 using an If directive. I'm not sure all php_flag commands work this way but some do.

For example,

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'">
    php_flag xdebug.remote_autostart On
    php_flag xdebug.remote_enable On
</If>
```