# .htaccess rules by IP address

Tags: php, .htaccess, access-control

I'm looking for a way to enable some .htaccess rules on an IP or hostname basis (hopefully with regex). This is all over stackoverflow, but I can't find any that are **generic rules** that apply to a block of rules (And in fact, that may not be how .htaccess works. I'm not sure!).

I do NOT need a rewrite rule. I do NOT need access/deny flags. I just want to change some PHP flags and file behavior for some development IP addresses on a few of our servers.

For example, to enable debug mode /error_log/

```
<magical_ip_filter_tag "123.456.78.901">
  php_flag display_startup_errors on
  php_flag display_errors on
  php_flag html_errors on
  php_flag log_errors on
  php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
</magical_ip_filter_tag>
```

Note that I do not need a PHP solution for PHP debugging, this is just an example.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess turn on php flags if certain IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052411/htaccess-turn-on-php-flags-if-certain-ip-address)

Comment: Apache v2.2.22, @JimLewis I wasn't able to find a question like that from searching, thanks. Although the answer there is not particularly what I was hoping for, I guess there may not actually be an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually find many comments/posts saying this is not possible. That would have been possible easily in newer Apache versions (2.4 and newer).

However on older Apache `2.2*` This is something I have used as a **workaround solution**

1. Create a symbolic link of `/index.php` and name it something like `/myinde.php` using this command:

   ```
   ln -s index.php myindex.php
   ```
2. Add this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.456\.78\.901$
   RewriteRule !^myindex.php/ myindex.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

   <Files myindex.php>
     php_flag display_startup_errors on
     php_flag display_errors on
     php_flag html_errors on
     php_flag log_errors on
     php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
   </Files>
   ```

`RewriteRule` on top forwards all the requests from your IP address to `/myindex.php` making original URI available as `PATH_INFO`.

Then block of code inside `<Files myindex.php>` is executed for the file `myindex.php`.

Comment: Did you mean `ln -s` instead of `ls -n` to create a symoblic link? I do see the workaround here, take the user to a page that normal users won't get to then check if they are visiting that page. Will this replace the functionality of the normal index.php, though? or am I supposed to re-include the standard index.php from within myindex.php?

Comment: Sorry for typo, yes I meant `ln -s`. No you don't need to include `index.php` since `myindex.php` is just symbolic link of `index.php`

Comment: Oh I get it! I wasn't clear on what a symbolic link was. "Symbolic link is a special type of file that contains a reference to another file". Sounds like this would be a good enough workaround. It's too bad it requires a serverside command, but for me at least, that's not an issue. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. I am using this trick myself on couple of websites.